# @Html.Raw along with Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm wondering what @Html.Raw does here along with Url.Action:

```
<form action="@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Index", "Home"))" method="get" id="formfilter">
    <input type="hidden" name="filter" value="true" />
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>

... etc.
```

I read that it encodes HTML but what it  does in this particular case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Url.Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_UrlHelper_Action_System_String_System_String_) generates a fully qualified URL to an action method by using the specified action name and controller name. Then the function [Html.Raw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2#System_Web_WebPages_Html_HtmlHelper_Raw_System_String_) is made to wrap HTML markup in an [HtmlString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.htmlstring?view=netframework-4.8) instance so that it is interpreted as HTML markup.

Comment: Ok but using this: ```Url.Action("Index", "Home")``` I just go to method Index in Home controller, so what markups Html.Raw wraps here? I don't understand, could you give simple example please?